# How do I make a parent Widget know that its children's Futures completed?

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I have a set of components that trigger a future on `initState` and render using a `FutureBuilder`. While they are still loading, they load a `CircularProgressIndicator`.

Because these futures complete at random times, I'm having a lot of flickering and the UX is terrible. Ideally, I should have 1 `CircularProgressIndicator` in the parent and only render the children once their futures are completed.

I cannot really transfer all these futures to the parent because these compoennts are dinamically generated from an API response. My only hope is to be able to "tell" the parents that their futures are completed.

I thought of using an `InheritWidget` to keep track of all futures. My problem is that, these futures start in `initState` and I don't have the `BuildContext` there to access the `InheritWidget`.

How do I make a parent Widget know that its children's Futures completed?

Comment: "I cannot really transfer all these futures to the parent because these compoennts are dinamically generated from an API response." Couldn't you dynamically build a `List<Future<void>>` and then have the parent widget wait for the result of [`Future.wait`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future/wait.html) on that list?

Comment: @jamesdlin Hey James. You have been on SO for exactly 1 month more than me. Cheers from a kindred old developer. So, I'm rendering a tree of custom Markdown elements that may decide to do their own data fetching. I was hoping for a simpler solution. But I can traverse the Markdown tree and pre-fetch all data beforehand. I guess I will have to do that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a callback function to the child widget which is defined in the parent widget class.

```
class Parent extends StatelessWidget {

  void onFutureComplete() {
    // do after future completed
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Child(
      onFutureComplete: onFutureComplete,
    );
  }
}

class Child extends StatelessWidget {

  final void Function() onFutureComplete;

  Child({
    this.onFutureComplete
  }

  void somethingHappens() {
    //await future here
    onFutureComplete();
  }
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid prop drilling because these components can be several layers deep. But my options are, either this, or fetching everything at the top level. I will deal with that. Thanks

Comment: I was assuming that the child is the direct child of the parent. Thats why a callback function is very easy to implement. If there are several layers between parent and child then consider InheritedWidget or the Provider package.